# Drupal 8 Do Something After Dialog Close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, drupal-8

I have this link which trigger open dialog using Drupal 8

i need do something in JS when dialog close

What i should write?

```
<div class="fullcalendar-bottom-btn add-event-btn">
<a id="calendar-add-event"  href="{{ language }}fullcalendar-view-event-add?entity={{ entity_id }}&bundle={{ options.bundle_type }}&start_field={{ options.start }}&end_field={{ options.end }}&destination={{ path('<current>') }}" class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="dialog" data-dialog-renderer="off_canvas" data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:400}">{{ 'Add event'|t }}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: For anyone here: see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/303119/7580

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with this right now.

In theory, `data-dialog-options` should accept any valid options accepted by [jQuery UI Dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) , but there aren't any examples in core that use `close` or `beforeClose`.